# Check for pixel spacing between two folder images

Tags: python, performance

Im trying to match the pixel spacing between two folders, here matches has 994 keys and it shows that i may take more than a day to compute this. Is there any way i can speed up this operation.

the load series function looks like this

```
import SimpleITK as sitk
def load_series(path):
    reader = sitk.ImageSeriesReader()
    dicom_names = reader.GetGDCMSeriesFileNames(path)
    reader.SetFileNames(dicom_names)
    return reader.Execute()

import csv
bar = ProgressBar()
file = open('BenignTest.csv', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(file)
for item in bar(matches.keys()):
    for case in matches[item]:
        load_case = load_series(case)
        if load_case.GetSpacing() == load_series(item).GetSpacing():
            writer.writerow((item , case))
            break
```

The matches dictionary looks like this,

```
{'/mnt/sdd1/DSB2017/stage1/0030a160d58723ff36d73f41b170ec21': ['/mnt/sde1/Cancer/128443/01-02-1999-LSS-59120/2-0OPAGELSPLUSD3602.512060.00.11.5-98506',
  '/mnt/sde1/Cancer/213485/01-02-1999-ACRIN-13247/3-0OPAGELSPLUSLUNG3502.51204026.71.5-85097',
  '/mnt/sde1/Cancer/206342/01-02-1999-ACRIN-68321/3-0OPAGELSPLUSLUNG3702.51205033.31.5-72233',
  '/mnt/sde1/Cancer/200209/01-02-2000-CRIN-10216/3-1OPAGELSPLUSLUNG4002.51204026.71.5-42354']...........}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Cross-posted from [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51835981/5069029)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest improvement that you can do right now is to avoid recomputing the same reference image over and over for each `case` of an `item`: just store `load_series(item).GetSpacing()` before looping over each `case`.

You can also use [`writer.writerows`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows) and feed it a list or a generator instead of `writer.writerow`. This should optimize disk writes a bit, even though reading images should be the task that take up the most resources here.

Proposed improvements:

```
import csv
import SimpleITK as sitk


def load_series(path):
    reader = sitk.ImageSeriesReader()
    dicom_names = reader.GetGDCMSeriesFileNames(path)
    reader.SetFileNames(dicom_names)
    return reader.Execute()


def generate_equal_spacing(matches, progress_bar=None):
    items = matches.keys()
    if progress_bar is not None:
        items = progress_bar(items)

    for item in items:
        reference_spacing = load_series(item).GetSpacing()
        for case in matches[item]:
            if load_series(case).GetSpacing() == reference_spacing:
                yield (item, case)
                break


def main(matches, output_filename='BenignTest.csv'):
    with open(output_filename, 'w') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(generate_equal_spacing(matches, ProgressBar()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main({
        '/mnt/sdd1/DSB2017/stage1/0030a160d58723ff36d73f41b170ec21': [
            '/mnt/sde1/Cancer/128443/01-02-1999-LSS-59120/2-0OPAGELSPLUSD3602.512060.00.11.5-98506',
            '/mnt/sde1/Cancer/213485/01-02-1999-ACRIN-13247/3-0OPAGELSPLUSLUNG3502.51204026.71.5-85097',
            '/mnt/sde1/Cancer/206342/01-02-1999-ACRIN-68321/3-0OPAGELSPLUSLUNG3702.51205033.31.5-72233',
            '/mnt/sde1/Cancer/200209/01-02-2000-CRIN-10216/3-1OPAGELSPLUSLUNG4002.51204026.71.5-42354',
        ],
        ...
    })
```

Comment: In addition: [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) may increase performance further if a lot of the files are the same.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want each image's spacing information, you don't actually need to read the images, just the header info.

Here is a SimpleITK example showing how to read an image's meta-data information without loading the pixels.

https://simpleitk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Examples/DicomImagePrintTags/Documentation.html

So change your load_series function something like this:

```
def load_series_spacing(path):
    reader = sitk.ImageSeriesReader()
    dicom_names = reader.GetGDCMSeriesFileNames(path)
    reader.SetFileNames(dicom_names)
    reader.ReadImageInformation();
    return reader.GetSpacing()
```

And then, of course, adjust the comparisons in the main routine accordingly, since we're returning spacing, not the actual images.

Comment: Hi Dave, Thanks for your inputs, But when i run your function, i get this `AttributeError: 'ImageSeriesReader' object has no attribute 'ReadImageInformation'` any ideas on this ?

Comment: Oops, my bad.  The method ReadImageInformation is in the class ImageFileReader, not ImageSeriesReader.  So you can get the header info for each individual slice.  Then GetSpacing would return the X-Y pixel spacing.  If you want the Z spacing, you'll have to do some math from the Origins of neighboring slices.